# Python - Making an user input a concatenated string

Tags: python, list, input, concatenation

I'm currently learning Python as a beginner and working on solving some example projects and came across this issue which I'm not sure how to deal with. The section of my code is shown below:

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]            
Y = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']

print('Please insert a position')
input()
if input() == str(X[0]) + Y[0]:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

I have 2 separate lists, and I take user inputs that are a concatenation of these two lists e.g. 1a or 7e. And I want to ensure that the user input matches any combination of the concatenation of [X][Y]. Like if a user inputs 6d, it would come back as true. And if a user inputs 3p for example, it comes back as false. Many thanks!

Comment: I've just tried this but for any input it results in true. Even for inputs that are not true concatenations of the two lists. I tried 9t for example and it came back as true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd check the length and then check each character individually against the appropriate list. Note you're also calling `input()` twice.

```py
user_input = input()
if len(user_input) == 2 and int(user_input[0]) in x and user_input[1] in y:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the individual input char's existence in X and Y.

```py
    choice = input()
    if int(choice[0]) in X and choice[1] in Y:
       print("True")
    else:
       print("False")
```